# How to remove duplicate data in list view with firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

> ** **SOLVED** **** **SOLUTION IN BELOW POST ******* SOLUTION IN BELOW POST** ******* **

**Classmate's i get a headcache to how resolve to remove duplicate data in a listview with firebase. I need only 1 item data to show in listview.
Showing to example in screen shot**

[image]

> Actual Code:

```
  ArrayList<ShowCliente> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    final ArrayAdapter<ShowCliente> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);

   newListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
 gDatabase.child("cliente").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ShowCliente show = dataSnapshot.getValue(ShowCliente.class);
            myList.add(show);
            //myList.clear();

            //*********************************
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            checkEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

> Last trying code: **This my attemps on this day to resolve this problem, any Don't work, post it to you knowledge :(**

```
        //*************************************23/03/2018 **** **************** ATTEMP 1

    //VARIABLES
ArrayList<ShowCliente> myList = new ArrayList<>();
List<ShowCliente> myShow = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ShowCliente> mList1 = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<ShowCliente>(myList));
//HashSet<ShowCliente> myHash = new HashSet<>();

     //LEE TODOS DATOS DE LOS CHILD DE LA BASE DE DATOS
          ShowCliente show  = dataSnapshot.getValue(ShowCliente.class);
          //DISMINUIR A 1 LOS CLIENTES REPETIDOS EN LISTA
            Iterator<ShowCliente> iteShow = myList.iterator();
            while(iteShow.hasNext()){
                ShowCliente ite = iteShow.next();
                if(ite.equals(show)) iteShow.remove();
            }
            myList.add(show);

          //ShowCliente key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
          //mKeys.add(key);
          arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          checkEmpty();


    //****************************************************************** ATTEMP 2

    for(DataSnapshot shot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ShowCliente show = shot.getValue(ShowCliente.class);
                    String compare = String.valueOf(show.getRazonsoc());
                   if(show.getRazonsoc() != compare){
                       myList.add(show);
                   }
            }


    //****************************************** ATTEMP 3

       ShowCliente show = dataSnapshot.getValue(ShowCliente.class);
            //myList.clear();
            myList.add(show);
            if(myList.indexOf(show) == myList.lastIndexOf(show)){
                myList.clear();

            }

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            checkEmpty();      

   //************************************** ATTEMP 4

    ShowCliente show = dataSnapshot.getValue(ShowCliente.class);

            myShow.add(show);

            HashSet<ShowCliente> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
            hashSet.addAll(myShow);
            myShow.clear();
            myShow.addAll(hashSet);

   //************************************ ATTEMP 5 

             for(DataSnapshot shot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ShowCliente show = shot.getValue(ShowCliente.class);
                String value = show.getRazonsoc();
                stringList.clear();
                stringList.add(value);

            }
```

**Gratefully for your comments and solutions**

Comment: Check if the object is in your list or not.

Comment: @Ibrahim i need remove the data not checking if exist or not

Comment: Please add your current code and delete your other coding attemps, its currently very unclear...

Comment: And I do not really know what you are trying to do, if you want to display only the last received item, then just call myList.clear() and then AFTER that myList.add(show)

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: You can try using a hash and set the key of the hash to the items String value. And then before adding any new item check if that key exists and if it does not exists then add or else do not add. This way you will have a unique list.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new List, do for loop over the old one and for each item in the old one, check if the new list `contains` the item, if it doesn't, add it to the new list.

This works if you have a good `hashCode` method on your model, if you don't, your two identical objects might have different hashCodes, thus making this technique (and other techniques that use hashCodes) ineffective.

In that case you either have to override the model's hashCode or if they have a unique field like `id`, use that to check for equality. (in the for loop above, for each item, do another for loop on the new list and check if none  of the items in the new list does not equal the item's id, add it to the list.)

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION (WORK FINE):**

```
 @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ShowCliente show = data.getValue(ShowCliente.class);
                myList.add(show);
                System.out.println("Duplicate:"+myList);
            }

            for(int i=0; i < myList.size(); i++){
                for(int j=0; j < myList.size(); j++){
                    if(myList.get(i).equals(myList.get(j))){
                        myList.remove(j);
                        //j;
                    }
                }
            }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            checkEmpty();
```