# How to avoid duplicate data in listview firebase

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I know this question was already asked and I followed [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457529/how-to-remove-duplicate-data-in-list-view-with-firebase-android).

My Firebase structure.

[image]

I need to display expensesName in listview. 
If data is repeated more than once it should display the data in listview for one time only, there is no duplicates of data and if there is no duplication data in firebase, it should  also be visible in listview.

I have tried the code below to get away the duplicate data but it doesn't work for data which is not repeated in firebase.

For Example in my firebase

```
oil // repeated 2 times
petrol //repeated 1 time
```

I need ouput as

```
oil
petrol
```

but actual output am getting is

```
oil
```

**MainActivity**

```
 listfirebaseref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Expenses Details").child(username).child(monthYr);

listfirebaseref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            expenseClassList.clear();
            int sum = 0;
            ExpenseClass expenseClass;
            Log.d("Tag", "on list Adpter");
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()) {
                    String exp = data.child("expensesName").getValue(String.class);
                    spacecraft = new ExpensesName(exp);
                    expenseClassList.add(spacecraft);
                    Log.d("Tag", " " + expenseClassList);
                    }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < expenseClassList.size(); i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < expenseClassList.size(); j++) {
                            if ((expenseClassList.get(i).equals(expenseClassList.get(j)))) {
                                expenseClassList.remove(j);
                                //j;
                            }
                            }
                            }
                            Log.d("Tag", " list Adpter");
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use HashSet instead of ArrayList?

Btw it's strange that you didn't get `concurrent modification exception`. You can't remove from the list while iterating it. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448671/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-arr)

```
Set<ExpensesName> expenseClassList = new HashSet<>();

   ....

   for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()) { 
                  String exp = data.child("expensesName").getValue(String.class);
                    spacecraft = new ExpensesName(exp);
                    expenseClassList.add(spacecraft);
                }
   }
```

Here your `expenseClassList` will contains only unique strings

Comment: Can you give some snippet to get through it.i really dnt know how to get my expected output.please help.me out

Comment: @PadmaPriya sure

Comment: Thank-you..I will try it and will say the result and I sorry to ask this simple doubt but I really don't know about hashmap.in the above code you have used `set<string>=new hashmap<>()` here we have to use `set<string>` or datamodel class name `set<expenseclass>`

Comment: @PadmaPriya In the above code, I used only HashSet.

Comment: @PadmaPriya HashSet is a collection that store only unique items

Comment: Ya i can understand sir. I have to use `set<expensesclass>` name of datamodel class instead of `set<string>`

Comment: @PadmaPriya Yes, you are right: `Set<ExpensesName > expenseClassList = new HashSet<>()`

Comment: Thankyou sir. I will try the code and let you know.thank you for your help sir

Answer (score -1):

use the HashSet instead of ArrayList

```
    HashSet<String> expenseClassList = new HashSet<>();

     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        expenseClassList.clear();
        int sum = 0;
        ExpenseClass expenseClass;
        Log.d("Tag", "on list Adpter");
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()) {
                if(!expenseClassList.contains(data.child("expensesName").getValue(String.class)){
                       expenseClassList.add(spacecraft);
                    }                    
                }
                        Log.d("Tag", " list Adpter");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```